# Combinatorical problem of food store

Tags: combinatorics

> There are four shops selling three types of food each.
> There are n people who each buy exactly one food at each shop. For each three people have at least one shop where all three types of the food are bought. Find the maximum value of n that possible

explanation : all the shops selling the same 3 types of food.

Let A,B,C and D are the food stores and x,y and z are the food. And let p is one of x,y and z. I'm not sure to my solution but i got this construction of 7 people is valid.

```
                 A       B       C       D
                 x       y       z       p
                 x       z       y       p
                 y       x       z       p
                 y       z       x       p
                 z       x       y       p
                 z       y       x       p
```

with those 6 people we have each three people have at least one shop where all three types of the food are bought. Then I can make some random permutation of food that bought by the seventh people, for example: the seventh people buy type x of food in all shops. Then i can make another valid construction.

```
                 A       B       C       D
                 x       y       z       y
                 x       z       y       z
                 y       x       z       z
                 y       z       x       y
                 z       x       y       y
                 z       y       x       z 
                 x       x       x       x
```

but i can not make any other permutation of type of food for the 8th people. and that makes me think that 7 is the maximum value of n.

But if someone has any other idea please share because i need combinatorical solution.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.